# iOS How to save data in Core Data from Text Fields and show these data in tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Hi i am Newbie in iOS and first time working on Core Data my task is that i have three text fields [name, email, dob] an one save button when i put data i text fields and press save button then data from text field save in core data and move to next page to show data in tableview.
I have build core data file named as CoreData.xcdatamodeld and one entity and three attributes name, email and date of birth.

```
-(IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender{
    if (switchButton.isOn)
    {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObject *transaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Shruti" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        NSManagedObject *name = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"name" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSManagedObject *email = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"email" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSManagedObject *dob = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"dob" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [name setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
        [email setValue:self.emailTextField.text forKey:@"email"];
        [dob setValue:self.dobTextField.text forKey:@"dob"];

        NSLog(@"Switch is On and data is saved in Core Data");

        TableViewController *objOfView = [[TableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objOfView animated:YES];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Switch is Off and data not saved in Core Data");
    }
}
```

In core data i have entity name as Shruti nad three attributes name as name email and dob.
Is it right if not then where i am wrong?

Comment: when i press then app crashed with error

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Shruti''

Comment: Are you sure that your persistentStoreCoordinator is valid/created correctly?

Comment: You've created a `NSManagedObject` for *transaction, but you're not setting value to it. Aren't your name, email, and dob suppose to be attributes of *transaction??

Answer (score 2):

If you've set up your Entity and Attributes correctly then you should be able to add with something like this.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *transaction = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Shruti" inManagedObjectContext:context];


[transaction setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
[transaction setValue:self.emailTextField.text forKey:@"email"];
[transaction setValue:self.dobTextField.text forKey:@"dob"];

// Save the context
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Save Failed! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

But it looks like you've created four different entities, rather than one entity with three attribute. 
Go back to your data model file and make sure your `Shruti` has it's three attribute. If not simply create one by pressing "+" button, set it's name, and set it's attribute's type as "String".
And make sure to delete those Entities name, email, and dob. Hope this will help.